# Executing Sybase ASE procedure in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I am trying to execute a Sybase ASE procedure in SQL Developer. It works fine in isql, but in SQL Developer it does not get executed.

When I execute it using 'Execute' command all I get is 'Procedure succeeded'.

Can you please let me know if there is any way to it?

Comment: We're not meant to be a Sybase ide...we're a tool to migrate Sybase to Oracle

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thanks for your response. I forgot to add that I have connected to Sybase DB from SQL Developer through third party JDBC Driver. I am able to run queries but not able to execute procedures.

Comment: sure you can execute them, we're just not setup to receive the results as a query set in the grid

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Is there anyway to see the procedure output/result?

Comment: You can try this http://dermotoneill.blogspot.com/2010/11/workheet-hints.html?m=1